# Google Analytics - Create custom report based on 2 events

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics, web-analytics

I am trying to create a report based on 2 events in Google Analytics. Event A is triggered when a user views a contact form and Event B is triggered when the user submits the form.

What would be the best way to create a report which displays the conversion rate based on the data received from Events A and B above?

So basically the percentage of users that viewed the form and then went on to submit it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about programing

Comment: Thanks for your help DalmTo. Was really helpful. Where would you suggest I ask this question then?

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ is probably the best place for this.   Welcome to stack.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction.